# How to make those cool CTRL and ALT etc signs in SO?

Tags: support, markdown

I've been going thru the formatting help, but I cannot find how to make those cool <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> signs, the ones like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029548/picking-up-keystrokes-ctrl-alt-q)

Comment: I am sorry if this is a duplicate, also, it is the first time I ever heard the word __glyph__ . Sounds like a character from LOTR

Comment: I don't know what your native language is, but it's the same glyph that's embedded in heiroglyphics.

Comment: Thank you, I already googled that. For those of you still wondering what it means: _A glyph /ˈɡlɪf/ is an element of writing: An individual mark on a written medium that contributes to the meaning of what is written._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originally answered here: [Keyboard Glyphs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5527/keyboard-glyphs/5528#5528), you can use the `<kbd>` HTML tags.

```
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>
```

Makes: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>

You **cannot** use keyboard glyphs in comments. [Can I place <kbd></kbd> in a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132923/can-i-place-kbd-kbd-in-a-comment)

Comment: testing if they work in comments <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>

Comment: any ideas here? How to do the same in comments? I have seen this done.

Comment: Ok, mistaken with last comment. Can't be done.